# How should be an action of the reducer should be dispatched from a functional component such that the state changes immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using reactjs along with react-redux. I have a reducer PersonalReducer.js which has an action that I want to dispatch in the parent component. On dispatching the state of the component is changed while rendering but not after the action is dispatched.

PersonalComponent.js

```
class Personal extends Component {

handleNext = () => {
        this.props.onNext();
        console.log(this.props.statePersonal); //LINE X
}
render() {
    console.log(this.props.statePersonal);//LINE Y
    // other code
    <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={this.handleNext}
        className={classes.button}
    >NEXT
    </Button>
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    statePersonal: state.personal,
    stateAcademic: state.academic,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onNext: () => dispatch({type:actionTypes.HANDLE_NEXT_PERSONAL}),
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Profile));
```

PersonalReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    firstName: '',
    valid: true,
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.HANDLE_NEXT_PERSONAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                valid: false,
                firstName: 'xyzzz',
            }
    }
    return state;
}
```

After pressing NEXT button: LINE X prints in console: { firstName: '', valid: true, } LINE Y prints in console: { firstName: 'xyzzzz', valid: false, }

But I want this state to be updated in handleNext() itself so that I can check for validity of my form. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the state to change immediately in handleNext? Please help I am way past my deadline. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's async, such logging always will show the prev state

Comment: How can I get the new state?

Comment: You will get the new state after a render

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an asynchronous operation here, and it is also linked to *mapStateToProps*. You can detect *props* changes with **componentDidUpdate** method and check the validity of your form there. The official documentation is: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate